# How to get error logcat from my Google play users?

Tags: android-studio, exception, google-play, logcat, android-vitals

I've lunched an app on **Google Play Store**, and some of my users, have Errors on the app:

> Errors that i don't see on emulator or on my device.

So I was wondering how can i get the error logcats of that users so i can debug them and improve my app, I've been reading Android Vital information but only shows the errors and ANR the stats, and can't find the logcat.

**Is there any way to get my users error logcats**, or should I implement a function on my app to send the logcat through internet to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Firebase Crashlytics SDK which will automatically send errors that occur on the user's device to firebase that you can see on firebase console. You'll be able to find in which activity/fragment etc the error occurred and at what line.

From the Firebase website:

> Crashlytics intelligently groups an avalanche of crashes into a
>   manageable list of issues. It also provides information on why a crash
>   occurred and what happened leading up to it. With this insight, you
>   can uncover the root cause of crashes more quickly.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to check it out, to accept your answer

Comment: It's also not advisable to use logging in production since you may log sensitive information.